# Is there a way to remove a line fully?

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I'm using a one-line command to compile and print all of the animal names listed in a log file.

The WILD names are all listed in capital letters under the /wild directory.

The output should appear in the format of one name per line, with no duplicates:

```
ANT
BAT
CAT
```

I tried
 `grep 'wild' animal.txt | awk '{print $7}' | sed 's/[a-z0-9./]//g' | sort -u`

It showed what I want but I want to remove the whole string which contains special characters like -, # ? %
Below is a sample of the file `animal.txt`

```
191.21.66.100 - - [21/Aug/1995:05:17:57 -0400] "GET /wild/elvpage.htm#ZOO HTTP/1.0"
191.21.66.100 - - [01/Aug/1995:02:22:35 -0400] "GET /wild/S/s_26s.jpg HTTP/1.0" 
191.21.66.100 - - [01/Aug/1995:02:22:41 -0400] "GET /wild/struct.gif HTTP/1.0" 
191.21.66.100 - - [01/Aug/1995:02:27:34 -0400] "GET /wild/elvpage.htm HTTP/1.0" 
191.21.66.100 - - [01/Aug/1995:02:27:36 -0400] "GET /wild/endball.gif HTTP/1.0" 
191.21.66.100 - - [01/Aug/1995:02:27:37 -0400] "GET /wild/hot.gif HTTP/1.0" 
191.21.66.100 - - [01/Aug/1995:02:27:38 -0400] "GET /wild/elvhead3.gif HTTP/1.0" 
191.21.66.100 - - [01/Aug/1995:02:27:38 -0400] "GET /wild/PEGASUS/minpeg1.gif HTTP/1.0" 
191.21.66.100 - - [01/Aug/1995:02:27:39 -0400] "GET /wild/DOG/DOG.gif HTTP/1.0"
191.21.66.100 - - [01/Aug/1995:02:27:39 -0400] "GET /wild/SWAN/SWAN.gif HTTP/1.0" 
191.21.66.100 - - [01/Aug/1995:02:27:39 -0400] "GET /wild/ATLAS/atlas.gif HTTP/1.0" 
191.21.66.100 - - [01/Aug/1995:02:27:40 -0400] "GET /wild/LIZARD/lizard.gif HTTP/1.0"
```

Below is a sample of my output after running the command:

```
ATLAS
ATLAS-
CAT_
DOG
%FACT
-KWM
?TIL-
#ZOO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not allow only capital A-Z and remove everything else:

```
grep 'wild' animal.txt | awk '{print $7}' | sed 's/[^A-Z]//g'
```

from your example input, this will return:

```
PEGASUS
DOGDOG
SWANSWAN
ATLAS
LIZARD
```

If you need to: you can further cleanup empty lines by appending `|sed "/^$/d"` and then sort

Comment: ... and in case you don't like duplicates, you add `| sort | uniq` at the end :-)

Comment: Thank you Ron and Dominique for replying!  Your code is way much cleaner than mine. I'm still learning how to use all these commands!

Comment: Unfortunately no Ron. I'm still figuring out how to remove the whole line. In this case, it removed the ```#``` from ```#ZOO``` but I want it completely removed instead.

Comment: append `| grep -v "ZOO"` or to remove more than one matching lines `| egrep -v "ZOO|YARD|COFFEE"`

Comment: Ron, I managed to remove all the other lines that I don't want. Except one of it's only with a Single letter```E```. So when I ``` grep -v "E"``` It will remove all my other lines which contain the letter. So oh damn but you're an amazing guy Ron thanks for helping me!

Comment: try `grep -v "^E$"`

Comment: Ron you're a legend! Solved it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single GNU `sed` command:

```
sed -n 's!.*/wild/\([A-Z][A-Z]\+\)/.*!\1!p' animal.txt
```

Means:

- `-n`: Do not print every line.
- `s!X!Y!` Substitute X with Y.
- `.*/wild/\([A-Z][A-Z]\+\)/*`: find a capital letter followed by at least one capital letter and preceded by `wild/`. These should be followed by a `/` and anything. Capture (remember) the capital letters.
- `!\1!`: Replace whatever you found with the capital letter sequence.
- `p`: If it was a match then print the line.

Gives:

```
PEGASUS
DOG
SWAN
ATLAS
LIZARD
```

Comment: Perhaps `[A-Z]\{2,\}` might be more informative than `[A-Z][A-Z]\+` but wouldn't `[A-Z]\+` do?

Comment: Good point, my intention is to remove `S` in the input, or filter out any impossible single letter animal name.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/.*\/wild\/[^A-Z ]*([A-Z]+).*/!d # delete lines with no uppercase letters
        s//\1/                           # remove everything but uppercases letters
        H                                # append word to the hold space
        $!d                              # delete all lines but the last
        x                                # swap to the hold space
        :a                               # loop name space
        s/((\n[^\n]+).*)\2/\1/           # remove duplicates
        ta                               # repeat until failure
        s/.//' file                      # remove introduced newline
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk to get result:

```
grep 'wild' animal.txt | awk '
                          ($0 = $7)
                          {gsub(/\//, " ", $0)};        #replace '/' with space so we can separate $0 to ($1, $2, $3);
                          (NF == 3 && length($2) > 2)   #check if there is three word in line ($1, $2, $3) and then check if length($2) is more then 2 character
                                           {print $2}'
| sort -u
```

Answer:

```
grep 'wild' animal.txt | awk '
                     ($0 = $7) {gsub(/\//, " ", $0)}; 
                     (NF == 3 && length($2) > 2) {print $2}' | sort -u
```